# Error CS0436 : a resource has conflict with itself if the resource and caller is in a same folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webforms

I have a class named "**BaseHelper**" in my "**App_Code**" Folder.
This class contains a few static methods that I use in my projects that give me functionalities that I have to write multiple lines of code to use that functionality.

Now the problem is I have a few other helper methods in this folder. There is no problem with using this class' helper methods in the whole project but when i want to use methods in other helper methods that are in "**App_Code**" folder i get a warning like this:

> Warning   CS0436   The type 'BaseHelper' in
>   'C:\Users[Username]\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015...\App_Code\BaseHelper.cs' conflicts with the imported type
>   'BaseHelper' in '[Project Name], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in
>   'C:\Users[Username]\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015...\App_Code\BaseHelper.cs'. C:\Users[Username]\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2015\Projects...\App_Code\SiteManager.cs

And once more I should emphasize that the problem is only present when I want to use the helper methods in the same folder but not when I want to use from different folders. The problem is not only in the "**BaseHelper**" but every time I want to use a helper method in the same folder.

Because I want to use the classes throughout my project I used my project's name as name space and I've tried to use no namespace at all but didn't change anything.

Thanks in advance and sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow found out that the problem lies in the folder **App_Code** and the code files i put in there.

I don't know the exact problem and i'd be happy if anyone with the knowledge please enlighten me.

I solved the problem by simply moving all files to another folder and removing **App_Code** folder altogether